# Big-O Notation of Code snippet with nested for loops

Tags: python, big-o

I have the following code snippet:

```py
for i in range(n): 
    for j in range(n^2): 
        for k in range(i*j): 
            do_something() #This function is O(1)
```

I can tell that the complexity without the last for loop would be n^3. but I don't understand how to calculate the complexity of the last loop.

I had a previous example:

```py
for i in range(n): 
    for j in range(i): 
        do_something() #This function is O(1)
```

It had the solution n^3(This is wrong. It is Actually n^2. I will still keep it here as it might help others understand where my error came from). which made sense to me. the first loop runs n times. the second loop runs about (n^2+n)/2 times according to the Gauss sum. O(n)*O(n^2)=O(n^3)

When I try to do the same for the code snippet in question. I get n*n^2*n^6=O(n^9) (i*j has it's maximum at n^3 which I plucked into the Gausssum: (n^6+n^3)/2.

But that seems wrong to me. Can someone help? Maybe also help me understand the other example I gave a little better?

Comment: `^` operator in Python is xor. You probably mean `**`.

Comment: You second example is O(n\*\*2), not O(n\*\*3).  Think of it this way:  `i` is always < `n`, so this loop nest is strictly faster than two nested `range(n)` loops, which are clearly O(n\*\*2), right?

Comment: The maximum value of ij is n^3. That means the entire loop is O(n^6), by simply replacing ij by n^3. In particular it is also O(n^9), it is Big-O after all. However I'm not sure where n^9 came from.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you to everyone. I now see my mistake. I was acting like the very inner for look (for k in range(i*j)) was completely seperate from the two outerloops. I must have written down the wrog solution for the other example which threw me off. Thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop runs `i * j` times. As `i` and `j` can take values up to `n` and `n^2`, respectively, the worst-case scenario is when `i = n` and `j = n^2`. So the inner loop has a time complexity of `O(n * n^2) = O(n^3)`.

The middle loop runs `n^2` times, and the inner loop inside it has a time complexity of `O(n^3)`. So the time complexity of the middle loop is `O(n^2 * n^3) = O(n^5)`.

The outer loop runs `n` times, and the middle loop inside it has a time complexity of `O(n^5)`. So the time complexity of the outer loop is `O(n * n^5) = O(n^6)`.

Therefore `O(n^6)` is the total time complexity of this.

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate the big O with trick that for every i*j in third loop we can say two first loops are O(1).
So the answer is going to be sigma i = 1 to n i * (sigma j = 1 to n ^ 2). sigma j = 1 to n ^ 2 = 1 + 2 + ... + (n ^ 2 - 1) + n^2 = (n^2)(n^2 + 1) / 2 = O(n^4)
So answer is sigma i = 1 to n i * something from O(n ^ 4). so we say (1 + 2 + ... + (n - 1) + n) * O(n ^ 4) = n * (n + 1) / 2 + O(n^4) = n^2 * O(n^4) = O(n ^ 6)